# Sorting array with specific keywords/string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on logframe and i want to sort my array in this order

- Impact
- Outcomes
- Output
- Activities

and i have array like this

```
{ id : 15 , parentId : 18 , type : OUTPUT , sequence : 1 },
{ id : 16 , parentId : 15 , type : OUTCOME , sequence : 1 },
{ id : 18 , parentId : null , type : IMPACT , sequence : 1 },
{ id : 14 , parentId : null , type : IMPACT , sequence : 2 },
{ id : 17 , parentId : 14, type : OUTCOME , sequence : 1 },
```

this was a raw data from database and order by via sequence

I wanted to sort it with all "IMPACT" type to be 1st on array and then so on ...

```
{ id : 18 , parentId : null , type : IMPACT , sequence : 1 },
{ id : 14 , parentId : null , type : IMPACT , sequence : 2 },
{ id : 16 , parentId : 15 , type : OUTCOME , sequence : 1 },
{ id : 17 , parentId : 14, type : OUTCOME , sequence : 2 },
{ id : 15 , parentId : 18 , type : OUTPUT , sequence : 1 },
```

Comment: Duplicate covers the sorting array of objects by specific property part; if you need a “special order” within the values of that property, you can achieve that for example by specifying them in an array in the right order, and then check what index.

Comment: i was really looking for special order but i dont know the right term on it. thanks for pointing it out :) really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Array.sort, and pass your own custom comparison function to it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

For example, something like this should work:

```
arrayFromDatabase.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.type === IMPACT && b.type !== IMPACT) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.type !== IMPACT && b.type === IMPACT) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return a.sequence - b.sequence;
    }
});
```

Note that for brevity's sake, I left the other types you mentioned as an exercise for the reader.